# Можно ли указать зависимый атрибут для атрибута? Как это сделано у атрибута Guid -> ComImport?

Tags: c#, .net, атрибуты

Мне нужно что бы один аттрибут не мог быть установлен без другого. Можно ли указать эту зависимость, что бы при отсутствии требуемого создавать ошибку при компиляции?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Delegate, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class ComMethodIdAttribute : Attribute
{
    public uint Id { get; protected set; }

    public ComMethodIdAttribute(uint id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

Данному аттрибуту нужен аттрибут `UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, это невозможно задать в самих атрибутах. Во всяком случае, в [исходниках](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/attributes.cs,aed9b3101252f25d) у этих атрибутов ничего такого нет.

Я нарыл следующее: ошибка компилятора CS0596 вот [здесь](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23326) имеет название `ERR_ComImportWithoutUuidAttribute`. Поискав по нему, я нашёл [следующий](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Symbols/Source/SourceNamedTypeSymbol.cs,dbd233630ad26046,references) код в исходниках компилятора Roslyn.

Название метода: `PostDecodeWellKnownAttributes` - говорит само за себя. В компилятор забита реакция на проверки некоторых хорошо известных атрибутов.

---

Думаю, вполне можно написать [собственный](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-Writing-a-Custom-Analyzer-&-Code-Fix) анализатор кода, который будет отлавливать обязательность совместного использования ваших атрибутов. Естественно, этот анализатор нужно будет устанавливать отдельно на всех машинах разработчиков вашего проекта. Впрочем, это выполняется автоматически при открытии солюшена с подключенными анализаторами.